# Obtener todos los registros diferentes sin repetir el campo usuario en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Estoy tratando de obtener todos los registros distintos de la colección `empeladoCosto` por medio del campo `usuario`, estoy haciendo una consulta de agregación ya que también requiero la informacion del usuario.

La consulta que tengo armada es esta, pero solo me devuelve los usuarios y lo que yo ocupo es que me traiga la informacion de `empleadoCosto`:

```
db.getCollection("empleadoCosto").aggregate(
    [
        {
            $lookup: // Equality Match
            {
                from: "usuarios",
                localField: "usuario",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "usuario"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$usuario',
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                  usuario: '$usuario',
                },
            }
        },
        {
            $replaceRoot: {
                newRoot: '$_id.usuario'
            }
        },
    ]
);
```

Esta es la informacion de la colección `usuarios`:

```
[
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ecfd64d59a79c3f94edda55"), 
        "clave" : "JCGG19", 
        "estatus" : true, 
        "permitirEMails" : true,
        "celular" : NumberInt(0), 
        "telefono" : NumberInt(0), 
        "nombre" : "JUAN CARLOS BIT PROD",
    },
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dc5c9e1ef48e93ad301cbef"), 
        "clave" : "JCGG", 
        "nombre" : "JUAN CARLOS SUPORT",
        "notificarPendientes" : false, 
        "registrado" : true, 
        "estatus" : true, 
        "celular" : NumberInt(1),
        "extension" : NumberInt(1), 
        "telefono" : NumberInt(123456)
    },
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e14b34a7b4bee26d42e0f89"), 
        "clave" : "JCGG12", 
        "nombre" : "JUAN CARLOS CLI 1", 
        "estatus" : true, 
        "telefono" : NumberInt(0), 
        "extension" : NumberInt(0), 
        "celular" : NumberInt(0),
        "registrado" : true
    }
]
```

Esta es la información de la colección de `empleadoCosto`:

```
[
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("60105effcf97872a786b9ca3"), 
        "usuario" : ObjectId("5dc5c9e1ef48e93ad301cbef"), 
        "costoHora" : NumberInt(260), 
        "costoUso" : NumberInt(30), 
        "disponibleDesde" : ISODate("2021-01-01T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "disponibleHasta" : ISODate("2021-01-31T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "estatus" : true,
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("601066accf97872a786b9ca4"), 
        "usuario" : ObjectId("5dc5c9e1ef48e93ad301cbef"), 
        "costoHora" : NumberInt(260), 
        "costoUso" : NumberInt(30), 
        "disponibleDesde" : ISODate("2021-01-01T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "disponibleHasta" : ISODate("2021-01-31T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "estatus" : false,
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("601b3c45c38d5d2bac5feff6"), 
        "usuario" : ObjectId("5e14b34a7b4bee26d42e0f89"), 
        "costoHora" : NumberInt(260), 
        "costoUso" : NumberInt(30), 
        "disponibleDesde" : ISODate("2021-01-01T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "disponibleHasta" : ISODate("2021-01-31T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "estatus" : true,
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("602c6fe1d24df93a5a9b3dab"), 
        "usuario" : ObjectId("5ecfd64d59a79c3f94edda55"), 
        "costoHora" : NumberInt(260), 
        "costoUso" : NumberInt(30), 
        "disponibleDesde" : ISODate("2021-01-01T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "disponibleHasta" : ISODate("2021-01-31T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "estatus" : false,
    }
]
```

Respuesta que deseo obtener, todos los `empeladoCosto` donde el campo `usuario` no se repita:

**NOTA:** No es necesario que la informacion del campo `usuario` salga, mientras el campo contenga el `ObjectId`.

```
[
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("60105effcf97872a786b9ca3"), 
        "usuario" : { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ecfd64d59a79c3f94edda55"), 
            "clave" : "JCGG19", 
            "estatus" : true, 
            "permitirEMails" : true,
            "celular" : NumberInt(0), 
            "telefono" : NumberInt(0), 
            "nombre" : "JUAN CARLOS BIT PROD",
        }, 
        "costoHora" : NumberInt(260), 
        "costoUso" : NumberInt(30), 
        "disponibleDesde" : ISODate("2021-01-01T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "disponibleHasta" : ISODate("2021-01-31T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "estatus" : true,
    },
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("601b3c45c38d5d2bac5feff6"), 
        "usuario" : { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e14b34a7b4bee26d42e0f89"), 
            "clave" : "JCGG12", 
            "nombre" : "JUAN CARLOS CLI 1", 
            "estatus" : true, 
            "telefono" : NumberInt(0), 
            "extension" : NumberInt(0), 
            "celular" : NumberInt(0),
            "registrado" : true
        }, 
        "costoHora" : NumberInt(260), 
        "costoUso" : NumberInt(30), 
        "disponibleDesde" : ISODate("2021-01-01T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "disponibleHasta" : ISODate("2021-01-31T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "estatus" : true,
    },
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("602c6fe1d24df93a5a9b3dab"), 
        "usuario" : { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5dc5c9e1ef48e93ad301cbef"), 
            "clave" : "JCGG", 
                "nombre" : "JUAN CARLOS SUPORT",
                "notificarPendientes" : false, 
                "registrado" : true, 
                "estatus" : true, 
                "celular" : NumberInt(1),
                "extension" : NumberInt(1), 
                "telefono" : NumberInt(123456)
            }, 
        "costoHora" : NumberInt(260), 
        "costoUso" : NumberInt(30), 
        "disponibleDesde" : ISODate("2021-01-01T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "disponibleHasta" : ISODate("2021-01-31T00:47:33.899+0000"), 
        "estatus" : false,
    }
]
```

Comment: En el resultado que propones, el usuario `5ecfd64d59a79c3f94edda55` aparece repetido, ¿Así esta bien? tengo esa duda porque mencionas que no deben repetirse los usuarios, saludos

Comment: En relación a los documentos en `empleadoCosto._id` para `...9ca3` y `...9ca4` donde el usuario `...301cbef` aparece repetido, no te interesa si regresa uno u otro en particular, simplemente regresar cualquiera de los dos, pues lo que buscas es descartar `usuario` repetido.

Comment: @g.4 disculpa mi error, no debe salir repetido ningún usuario, estaría excelente si regresará el último que fue insertado, si no es posible no tiene importancia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto mi problema de la siguiente forma.

Mi consulta iba por buen camino, solo me hacia falta agregar los Documentos principales

```
$group: {
    _id: {
      usuario: '$usuario',
    },
    unique: {
        // se agrega los documentos principales que tienen el mismo usuario
        $addToSet: '$$ROOT'
    },
}
```

El campo `unique` me devolvía un arreglo, de ese arreglo solo me interesaba 1 ya sea el que estuviese con el campo `"estatus" : true,` o el primer elemento del arreglo ya, que puede haber los registros de `empleadoCosto` del mismo `usuario` con estatus `false`.

Debido a que me devolvía un arreglo cambie el operador `$addToSet` por `$first` quedando el grupo de la siguiente forma:

```
$group: {
    _id: {
      usuario: '$usuario',
    },
    unique: {
        // se agrega el primer registro del arreglo encontrado
        $first: '$$ROOT'
    },
}
```

> **NOTA:** deseo poder aplicar también filtro por `estatus` cuando al menos un documento del arreglo  `unique` lo tenga como true y obtener ese documento con `'estatus': true`, si el arreglo `unique` tiene solamente estatus false me traiga el primero.